# Multiple has_term in if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    if ( has_term( 'flakt', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        noInstallModal();
        break;
    }
}
```

In Woocommerce cart, I want to display a message if the customer have one type of product category but not another, as in "you should really buy this to buy this" alert.

But I can't get the code to work with multiple product categories in the if statement. One works fine, but nothing happens if I add another statement with a &&.

```
if ( has_term( 'flakt', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && has_term( 'installation', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Forgot to explain. If the cart have products with category "flakt", but NOT products with category "installation", the message should show.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to solve it like this..

```
$flakt = false;
$install = false;

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   $product = $cart_item['data'];

   if ( has_term('flakt', 'product_cat', $product->get_id()) ){
       $flakt = true;
   }
   if ( has_term('installation', 'product_cat', $product->get_id()) ){
       $install = true;
   }
}

if($flakt && !$install){
   noInstallModal();
}
```

Comment: Didn't Work for me... Also tried this code 

if ( !has_term('term', 'taxonomy', $post->ID )) {}

Using a NOT operator

didn't work either

Comment: This is really weird you guys. Either portion of the IF would work on it's own but when combining both with an or || neither would work.
I had to use "if, elseif, else" just make the logic work.

Answer (score 4):

With multiple [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) in an if statement, **you should use "OR"** instead of "AND",:

```
if ( has_term( 'flakt', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) || has_term( 'installation', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {}
```

> You can use **directly an array of terms** with [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function:
>
> ```
> if ( has_term( array('flakt', 'installation'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {}
> ```

This should works too.

---

**Update related to your comment:**

As a product can have many product categories, if you want to be sure displaying a message only for 'flakt' product category and not for 'installation' product category you will use:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    if ( has_term( 'flakt', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        if ( ! has_term( 'installation', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            noInstallModal();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> **For the product ID:**
>
> You should use `$cart_item['product_id']` (instead of `$cart_item['data']->get_id()`) as product variarions will not work for your product categories…

Comment: I missed to explain one thing. Sorry!

If one product in cart have the category "flakt", but NOT "installation", the message should show. Is that possible?

Comment: Your solutions should work but for some reason does not. Maybe some issue with Wordpress / WooCommerce itself. I solved it in another way, but thank you!